# Spring MVC download PDF on chrome issue

Tags: android, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, pdf

I have two services to generate and download PDF files. First there is POST (for hiding data) which save data in session, generate unique id and return it.
Second service is GET (param is unique id from POST) which remove id from session, generate PDF and returns it as stream. It looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<byte[]> getData(
        @ApiParam(name="hash", value="hash", required=true)
        @RequestParam(value="hash", required = true) String hash,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Map reportData = reportsContext.getReportData(hash);

    /*generate PDF here*/   

    return new HttpEntity<>(report.getContent(), getHeaders(report));
}
```

and getHeaders() is:

```
private HttpHeaders getHeaders(ReportData report) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=".concat(report.getTitle()).concat(".pdf"));
    return headers;
}
```

It generally works fine on all browsers and systems but Android Chrome. First, I found out that Chrome on Android send two GETs (one from browser, second from download manager) - because hash was deleted, second GET thowed exception. Next step was saving generated stream in session (>.<) and returned it on second GET - despite returned streams was the same (when returning from getData()), second response is bad formated. I guess this is some kind of Spring issue, somehow it changes formatting.

There are initials of responses:
first GET:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-Powered-By: Express server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   content-disposition: attachment;
>   filename=operation_20052016.pdf content-type:
>   application/pdf content-length: 28626 date: Fri, 20 May 2016 07:51:08
>   GMT connection: close
>
> %PDF-1.4 %âăĎÓ

second GET:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-Powered-By: Express server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   content-disposition: attachment;
>   filename=operation_20052016.pdf content-type:
>   application/pdf transfer-encoding: chunked date: Fri, 20 May 2016
>   07:51:13 GMT connection: close
>
> 2000 "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLj

------------ANSWER------------

Finally I put manually producible attribute, like:

```
request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE, Sets.newHashSet(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf")));
```

just before returning correct PDF. In case of error I dont set produces attribute so it take default value.

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: 
Finally I put manually producible attribute, like:

```
request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE, Sets.newHashSet(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf")));
```

just before returning correct PDF. In case of error I dont set produces attribute so it take default value.